# Fastest way to delete files with 0 size

Tags: linux, bash, delete-file

I am in search of the fastest possible way to delete files with 0 size using bash.

I have hundreds of thousands of files with 0 size being generated (alongside valuable output) into a single output directory from a grep command run with GNU parallel. When grep finds a match the output file contains information. When grep does not find a match the output file is empty.

```
parallel -j $numcores "grepfunction {} > output_{}.fastq" ::: "${input_array[@]}"
```

I am using the following to remove the empty files but I would like to find a faster option.  In searching most of the solutions I have found use similar find based commands that work at similar speeds.

```
find results2/ -size 0 -delete
```

As suggested in the comment i have also tried the following

```
find ./results2 -size 0 -print0 |xargs -0 rm --
```

It is qualitatively slow but I will benchmark and report back.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe using `find` to get the files and `xargs` to perform the `rm` in parallel. Try and benchmark.

Comment: would be overall way more efficient if you modified your parallel thing to not generate files if there is no information.

Comment: I doubt there will be anything faster than `find results2/ -size 0 -delete`, as that is *one* process generating a number of system calls. `find` with `xargs` is at least three processes (`find`, `xargs`, and one or more calls to `rm`), and `rm` is going to do the same thing `find ... -delete` does: make some number of system calls to delete each file individually.

Comment: I *think* you'll find that `find ... | parallel -X rm` is quicker than `find ... | xargs rm ...` because `parallel` will, respecting ARGMAX, give as many files as possible to each invocation of `rm`.... though @chepner's answers are normally roughly 376,892 times better than mine :-)

Comment: `xargs` also will call its utility with multiple arguments.

Comment: `... -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P0 rm --` The `-P0` makes rm run in parallel, but I don't believe it will be any faster, because the underlying fileystem has to process the requests. I know - move to tmpfs.

Comment: Why don't you just delete the empty file in the `parallel` script?

Comment: Better yet, don't generate the zero-size files in the first place. `grepfunction {} | awk '{print > output_{}.fastq}'`, for example, will only create the file if `awk` receives any input in the first place. (The syntax might not be 100% correct in this example.)

Comment: See the duplicate question I referred you to in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53401132/prevent-grep-from-returning-an-empty-string-when-no-match-is-found)[

Comment: @Paul, I told you to run `xargs` in parallel: `find ./results2 -size 0 -print0 | xargs -0 
 -P 0 rm --`. But at the end, the performance depends on the filesystem. For a small, sequential file system, it will be the same, even slower due to the extra number of steps. In big, parallel filesystems, it can be several times faster. My experience in Lustre filesystems is that the parallel strategy decreases the total time quite a lot (although I didn't had a benchmark).

Comment: I've never had to use parallel, so I'm not exactly sure how it would work, but if your grep_function returns a non-zero status when not finding anything, you could do something like "grep_function {} >output_{}.fastq || rm -f output_{}.fastq" to remove the empty files within your parallel invocation.

Comment: Assuming the number of the valuable files is much less than number of empty ones. If possible, just copy out the valuable output, and then `rm -rf directory` containing the empty files. Solutions using `find -exec` or `find | xargs` are always slow on large input.

Answer (score 0):

(This should be a comment, but is too hard to read as a comment).

If you are going to run the jobs again you could make it part of the generating of the file:

```
parallel -j $numcores "grepfunction {} > output_{}.fastq ||
  rm output_{}.fastq" ::: "${input_array[@]}"
```

I assume the grep function returns true if match (like `grep` does).